# how to make a difference between two data files more efficient (run time)

Tags: perl

I have a code which compares values on some specific terms between two files. The main time-consuming part of the code as follows:

```
my @ENTIRE_FILE;
my %NETS;
my %COORDINATES;
my $INT=1;
my %IR_VALUES;
################################# READING
foreach my $IR_REPORT_FILE_1(@IR_REPORT_FILES){
   {
      open (FHIN, "<", $IR_REPORT_FILE_1) or die("Could not open $! for reading\n");
      # chomp(my @ENTIRE_FILE = <FHIN>);                            # READS THE ENTIRE FILE
      local undef $/;
      @ENTIRE_FILE = split(/\n(.*NET.*)/,<FHIN>);
      close (FHIN);
   }
   ############################### BUILDING HASH
   for my $i(1..$#ENTIRE_FILE/2){
     if($ENTIRE_FILE[$i*2-1]=~ /^----.*\s+"(\w+)"\s+/){
       my $net =$1;
       my @ir_values_of_net = split(/\n/,$ENTIRE_FILE[$i*2]);
       for my $val (@ir_values_of_net){
       push ( @{ $NETS{$INT}{$net} }, $val ) if ($val =~ /^r.*\s+m1|v1_viadg|v1_viabar|m2|ay_viabar|ay_viadg|c1\s+/); # NETS{1}{VDD}=array of values, NETS{1}{VSS}, NETS{1}{AVDD}
       }
     }
   }
   $INT++;                                          # For the next file:  NETS{2}{VDD}, NETS{2}{VSS}, NETS{2}{AVDD}
}
############################### COMPARISON
my $loop_count=0;
foreach my $net(keys %{ $NETS{1} }){
   print "net is $net\n";
   foreach my $file_1_net( @{ $NETS{1}{$net} }){
     my @sub_str_1 = split (' ', $file_1_net);
     foreach my $file_2_net ( @{ $NETS{2}{$net} } ){
       $loop_count++;
#        my @sub_str_1 = split (' ', $file_1_net);
       my @sub_str_2 = split (' ', $file_2_net);
       if(($sub_str_1[2] eq $sub_str_2[2])&&(($sub_str_1[3].$sub_str_1[4].$sub_str_1[5].$sub_str_1[6] eq $sub_str_2[3].$sub_str_2[4].$sub_str_2[5].$sub_str_2[6]) || ($sub_str_1[3].$sub_str_1[4].$sub_str_1[5].$sub_str_1[6] eq $sub_str_2[5].$sub_str_2[6].$sub_str_2[3].$sub_str_2[4]))){
         push (@{ $COORDINATES{$net}{X} },$sub_str_1[3],$sub_str_1[5]) if ($sub_str_1[3] && $sub_str_1[5]);
         push (@{ $COORDINATES{$net}{Y} },$sub_str_1[4],$sub_str_1[6]) if ($sub_str_1[4] && $sub_str_1[6]);
         my $difference=$sub_str_1[1]-$sub_str_2[1];
         if($sub_str_1[3]=~/^-/){
           push (@{ $MATCHED_RESISTORS{$net}{$sub_str_1[2].$sub_str_1[3].$sub_str_1[4].$sub_str_1[5].$sub_str_1[6]} }, $file_1_net,$file_2_net,$difference);
         }else{
           push (@{ $MATCHED_RESISTORS{$net}{$sub_str_1[2]."-".$sub_str_1[3].$sub_str_1[4].$sub_str_1[5].$sub_str_1[6]} }, $file_1_net,$file_2_net,$difference);
         }
         push (@{ $IR_VALUES{$net} }, $sub_str_2[1]);
         last;
       }
     }
   } 
   print max @{ $IR_VALUES{$net} };
   print "\nloop count is $loop_count\n";
   $loop_count = 0;
#    <>;  
}
```

I ran a profiler on the code. Below is the output on the above part of code:

[image: snapshot from html report of the profiler]

**Some statistics:**

1. For my testcase, the outer-most foreach has 3 elements. Below is the
   number of matched elements for each iteration:

> ```
> element_1: 14
> element_1: 316
> element_1: 8
> ```

2. The file sizes are 8.3 MB and 518.3KB.
3. Run time for the entire code is: 220s
4. My main concern is when I have a file size of 8.3MB each, and there are more numbers of matching between two files, the run-time is humongous e.g. 3 hours.

My question is really simple: How do I make my code run faster?

**Sample Data File_1:**

```
r6_2389         1.29029e-05     ay_viabar       23.076   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        3.68449e-06      -5.99170336965613
r6_2397         1.29029e-05     ay_viabar       22.948   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        3.68449e-06      -5.99170336965613
r6_2400         1.29029e-05     ay_viabar       22.82    57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        3.68449e-06      -5.99170336965613
r6_2403         1.29029e-05     ay_viabar       22.692   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        3.68449e-06      -5.99170336965613
r6_971          1.3279e-05      c1              9.492    45.742   -0.011   46.779   0.001    9.5589   10       0.0508653
```

**Sample Data File_2:**

```
r6_9261         0.00206167      ay_viabar       23.076   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0207546    
r6_9258         0.00206167      ay_viabar       22.948   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0161057    
r6_9399         0.00206167      ay_viabar       22.82    57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0127128    
r6_9486         0.00206167      ay_viabar       22.692   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0103186    
r6_1061         1.3279e-05      cb_pc_viadg     -6.696   44.157   -0.159   44.847   0.001    0        0        0
```

**Sample Output:**

```
   r6_9261         0.00206167      ay_viabar       23.076   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0207546    
    r6_9258         0.00206167      ay_viabar       22.948   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0161057    
    r6_9399         0.00206167      ay_viabar       22.82    57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0127128    
    r6_9486         0.00206167      ay_viabar       22.692   57.755   22.628   57.755   4.5      0        0        0.0103186
```

The sample output is basically pushed into another hash which is further processed. But building up this hash consumes about 90% of the total run-time as per the profiler.

Comment: Plus one for _humongous_. Why is the `split` in line 63 so slow? Can you give some example data? Possibly changing your algorithm might help. Also in line 64 you have `$sub_str_1[3] . $sub_str_1[4] . $sub_str_1[5] . $sub_str_1[6]` twice, which gets rebuilt for every iteration. You can move that outside the inner loop and put it in its own variable. That should save a little.

Comment: [Edit] the question, don't post code or data into comments please.

Comment: Great, thank you. Now we are missing `%MATCHED_RESISTORS` and `%COORDINATES` and `%NETS` and `%IR_VALUES` and `$loop_count`. Can you please turn the block of code into a [mcve] so I can run it?

Comment: I only pasted a part of the code. Do you want me to post the entire code?

Comment: No, not the entire code. I want you to turn it into something that reproduces the problem that I can run. Boil it down to taking input and processing it, and show what the final output should be, so we don't break it when we try to make it faster.

Comment: Edit done. Let me know whether it's enough to reproduce.

Comment: I think it'll be because you have a 3 deep loop, and that is going to be a multiplicative sort of a problem. You can _probably_ optimise there, but without more information it's hard to say how.

Comment: please shade some light on "more information"

Comment: OK. So - given your desired output - it _looks_ like you're value matching between file 1 and 2, and fields 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - (ay_viabar ...) and just printing the ones in file2 that exist in file1. Is that correct?

Comment: This is what I observed: Say, for $net=1, $NETS{1}{$net} refer to an array with 846 elements, $NETS{2}{$net} refer to an array with 115 elements. The matching elements are 42. The $loop_count in this case is 15660. Does this info help?

Comment: Thing is though - no, it doesn't, because we don't have the sample data needed to reconstruct a test case of 'nets'. Your runnable sample ... well, it runs, which is a good start. But because we've no example 'nets' data, then we can't run it ourselves, and optimise. 

I suspect you can splice your comparison values into a hash, and test key existence, but I can't give you a firmer answer.

Comment: E.g. at which point do you read 'sample1' that you've given us - does that connect with "NETS"? Because this looks like a lot simpler problem.

Comment: @Sobrique, first of all, column 2 , 3,4,5,6 should match between 2 files. and then print out both matching lines from two files(sorry about the op data example).  column 3,4,5,6 from one file can match with column 5,6,3,4. This should also be treated as a match.

Comment: Lovely. I'll draft a sample snippet that does that then.

Comment: Are your columns named? That might help clarity.

Comment: You can see in my code, before comparison, the sample 1 and 2 are read and kept in hash $NETS{1}{$net} and $NETS{2}{$net}

Comment: The columns are not named, but they follow exact order.

Comment: @SinanÜnür I am not a pro. this is rather a quick and dirty solution to something. this needs to run fast. having said that, are you suggesting that I store $sub_str_1[3].$sub_str_1[4].$sub_str_1[5].‌​$sub_str_1[6] to a variable and compare? wouldn't that also rebuilt for every iteration of the hash. becuase it needs to be rebuilt. Again, I am not a pro on either perl or data-structure

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are a pro or not. By looking at your code and your attemtps at explaining the problem, the only conclusion I am able to reach is that you do not fully understand the problem you are trying to solve. I am suggesting understanding the problem first, so that you do not end up writing conditions like that. Take a step back, and write everything again from scratch, if necessary. Even if someone here is able to double or triple the speed of your code here, this code is an unmaintainable mess which may be hiding much better optimization opportunities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so my first thought is - you've a 3 deep loop, and that will always be inefficient. We can probably trade memory for a lot of speed there.

Assuming the 'bigger' file is 'sample_1', otherwise swap them.

In this example - `sample_2` will consume memory proportionate to the number of rows - so we ideally want that to be the smaller file. You may need to swap the match/test around, depending on whether file1 cols 5,6,3,4 matches file2 or vice versa.

But hopefully this illustrates a useful concept for solving your problem, if not entirely solving it?

Something like this will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %is_match; 

open ( my $sample_1, '<', 'sample1.txt' ) or die $!;
open ( my $sample_2, '<', 'sample2.txt' ) or die $!;

#    first of all, column 2 , 3,4,5,6 should match between 2 files. 
# and then print out both matching lines from two files.     
#    column 3,4,5,6 from one file can match with column 5,6,3,4. 

while ( <$sample_2> ) { 
   my @row = split; 
   #insert into hash
   #this would be much clearer if the fields were named rather than numbered
   #I think. 
   $is_match{$row[3]}{$row[4]}{$row[5]}{$row[6]}++; 
   $is_match{$row[5]}{$row[6]}{$row[3]}{$row[4]}++; 
}

while ( <$sample_1> ) {
   my @row = split;
   #print the current line if it matches from the hash above.
   print if $is_match{$row[3]}{$row[4]}{$row[5]}{$row[6]};
}
```

Because this iterates each file once, it should be a lot faster. and because one of your files is small, then that's the one you should read first into memory.

With your sample data as provided, this gives you the desired output.

The first loop reads though the file, selects your interest fields and inserts them into a hash, based on your 4 keys.

And then it does so again for the other set of valid matching keys.

The second loop reads the other file, selects the keys and just checks if either combination exists in the hash. And prints the current line if it does.

Comment: I did not understand the second while loop. Care to explain! thanks!

Comment: okay, understood. but, I am losing the entire lines. In this way, I will only have the columns 2,3,4,5,6

Comment: I am wrong again. I can print the lines from $sample_1. Just another question: Is loop within loop is worse than having two separate loops, in terms of memory and speed?

Comment: Nested loops multiply operation. Two for loops - 100 elements - gives 10,000 iterations. Add an outer loop of 100, you have 1,000,000 iterations. So mostly, unrolling the loops - if you can or making one as small as possible avoids this problem. Hash traversal is an efficient operation, as it doesn't loop. It's a binary tree search. So is much faster.